# How can send this json to server with content type as application/x-www-form-urlencoded in android

Tags: android, json

How can I send this JSON to server API with content type as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in Android?

JSON is:

```
{
"id":1,
"name":"data1",
"datas":
[
{
"data_id":0,
"data_name":"data10"
},
{
"data_id":1,
"data_name":"data11"
},
{
"data_id":2,
"data_name":"data12"
}
]
}
```

Comment: Why? Why not use application/json?

Answer (score 0):

```
public JSONObject buildRequestBody() {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        Context context = getAppContext();
        if(context == null) {
            return jsonObject;
        }

        try {

            JSONObject datasJsonObject = new JSONObject();

            datasJsonObject.put("id", mId);
            datasJsonObject.put("name", mName);

            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

            for (Datas datas : mListDatas) {
                jsonArray.put(datas.getDataId());
                jsonArray.put(datas.getDataName());
            }

            datasJsonObject.put("datas", jsonArray);

            return datasJsonObject;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(CLASS_TAG, e.getMessage());
        }

        return jsonObject;
    }
```

---

### Datas.Java

```
public class Datas {

    private double mDataId;
    private String mDataName;

    public double getDataId() {
        return mDataId;
    }

    public void setDataId(double mDataId) {
        this.mDataId = mDataId;
    }

    public String getDataName() {
        return mDataName;
    }

    public void setDataName(String mDataName) {
        this.mDataName = mDataName;
    }
}
```